# issue accessing Array Items returned from Async call

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, promise, redux-thunk

I am returning an array from an async call in my action which then gets passed down to the reducer and finally back into the React. However, whenever I try to access the elements inside I get an error. My first guess was maybe my async call is wrong so I `console.log` everywhere. But everything seems fine except when I try to map over the array.

Here is the sequence of steps:

`Dispatch Action:`

```
.then(feeds => {
            console.log('Sending data to dispatch');
            console.log(`Testing this function -> ${JSON.stringify(feeds)}`);
            dispatch({
                type: 'RETRIEVE_FEEDS',
                payload: feeds,
            });
```

Initially feeds is an empty array in my reducer which then gets populated with this array.

`Reducer:`

```
 case 'RETRIEVE_FEEDS': {
            return { ...state, feeds: action.payload };
        }
```

Now in my `mapStateToProps` I receive the initial empty array and then the populated array from dispatch.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ feedState }) => {
    const { feeds } = feedState;
    console.log(`FeedState -> ${JSON.stringify(feedState.feeds)}`);
    console.log(`Is Array -> ${Array.isArray(feedState.feeds)}`);
    console.log(`Going to map through the array`);
    feedState.feeds.map(feed =>{
        console.log(`Feed -> ${JSON.stringify(feed)}`)
        console.log(`Feed ID -> ${feed.feedID}`)
    });
    return { feeds };
};
```

My only issue is that whenever I try to get something from the array it gets undefined.

These are my logs:

```
FeedState -> []

Is Array -> true

Going to map through the array

Sending data to dispatch

Testing this function -> [[{"feedID":"57dfnQuwUghupbRB7EEB","uploadedBy":"8Vmr0ZnVDPfgkCqSBWHXjaVEDYH3","videoURL":"","datePosted":"2017-12-08T14:24:37.323Z","tags":[],"isLike":false,"likes":{"countLikes":0}}],[{"feedID":"reYEcurssCV32WyQgOYp","uploadedBy":"8Vmr0ZnVDPfgkCqSBWHXjaVEDYH3","videoURL":"","datePosted":"2017-12-08T14:46:13.655Z","tags":[],"isLike":false,"likes":{"countLikes":0}}]]

FeedState -> [[{"feedID":"57dfnQuwUghupbRB7EEB","uploadedBy":"8Vmr0ZnVDPfgkCqSBWHXjaVEDYH3","videoURL":"","datePosted":"2017-12-08T14:24:37.323Z","tags":[],"isLike":false,"likes":{"countLikes":0}}],[{"feedID":"reYEcurssCV32WyQgOYp","uploadedBy":"8Vmr0ZnVDPfgkCqSBWHXjaVEDYH3","videoURL":"","datePosted":"2017-12-08T14:46:13.655Z","tags":[],"isLike":false,"likes":{"countLikes":0}}]]

Is Array -> true

Going to map through the array

Feed -> [{"feedID":"57dfnQuwUghupbRB7EEB","uploadedBy":"8Vmr0ZnVDPfgkCqSBWHXjaVEDYH3","videoURL":"","datePosted":"2017-12-08T14:24:37.323Z","tags":[],"isLike":false,"likes":{"countLikes":0}}]


Feed ID -> undefined
```

Comment: How and where are you trying to get stuff from the array?

Comment: I am simply mapping over the array in the mapStateToProps function

Comment: you map function doesn't do anything, why don't you do a foreach instead ?

Comment: Shouldn't your final console.log be "console.log(`Feed ID -> ${JSON.stringify(feed).feedId}`)"?

Comment: In the mapStateToProps function try returning something using the return keyword

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter I am returning the array

Comment: well try console.log(`Feed ID -> ${feed[0].feedID}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, from your logs, that each item in `feedState.feeds` is an array. So `feed.feedID` won't work. `feed[0].feedID` would work.

Also your `.map` function should return something and you should do something with your mapped array. i.e. result of `feeds.map`